# Highcharts Datetime X-Axis invalid date

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to plot a Highchart with the x-axis containing datetime values.

Example JSON datapoints :

```
"DATA": [
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:51 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:51:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,51)", 1433134260, null, 12.17],
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:53 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:53:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,53)", 1433134380, 1.28, null],
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:54 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:54:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,54)", 1433134440, null, 9.58],
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:56 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:56:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,56)", 1433134560, null, 7.78],
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:58 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:58:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,58)", 1433134680, 1.7, null],
        ["June, 01 2015 00:00:00", "01\/06\/2015 02:59 PM", "June, 01 2015 14:59:00", "Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,59)", 1433134740, null, 5.25]
]
```

Apart from the last 2 columns, all the columns represent the same datetime.

I need to plot the last 2 columns with a datetime column.

I have tried plotting with `Date.UTC` and the `millisecond` columns but getting the `invalid date` error.

The x-axis is defined as `datetime`.

Can you please advise the correct datetime format to use?

Edit 1 : I believe the UTC date format `Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,51)` instead of `"Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,51)"` should solve this. Trying to do the conversion now.

**Edit 2** : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nk8mybvk/)
The Fiddle is working as expected.

But while using the JSON call in the code, the error is occuring.

**JSON** :`[
    {
        "EMAIL": 1.05
        "PROBE_START_TIME_MS": 1433228764000,
    },
    {
        "EMAIL": 1.82,
        "PROBE_START_TIME_MS": 1433228944000,
    },
    {
        "EMAIL": "1.56",
        "PROBE_START_TIME_MS": 1433229064000,
    },
    {
        "EMAIL": 1.6,
        "PROBE_START_TIME_MS": 1433229244000,
    }]`

**Code** :

```
$.each(jsonResult, function(key,index) { 
            Email_Time.data.push(this.PROBE_START_TIME_MS, this.EMAIL);             
         });
```

**Output**:

[image: Current Output]

**Edit 3:** Working solution

```
$.getJSON("Json_Data.cfm", {}, function(EmailResult) {
        var Email_Time = {
                        name: "Email",
                        type: "line",
                        color: "#A5BC4E",
                        data: [],
                        marker: {
                                   radius: 1
                                }
                };

        $.each(EmailResult.DATA, function() { 
                //alert(this);
                Email_Time.data.push(this);             
         });

            options.series[0] = Email_Time;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

Comment: Three things: `Date.UTC(2015,6,1,14,59)` is 1st of July, not June. Remember, that months in JS are 0-11, where 0- Janyary, 1- December. Second, why can't you use timestamp (5th column)? That is timestamps (in seconds), so simply multiply them by 1000. And last thing, you said that all dates are the same, but timestamp is different? For example: `new Date(1433134740000)` => `Mon Jun 01 2015 06:59:00 GMT+0200`.

Comment: @PawełFus : I'm getting the correct result `new Date(1433134740000)` => `Mon Jun 01 2015 14:59:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)`.  Must be the different client locations issue. Anyhow, I'm still unable to display the correct dates on the charts. Its still showing `invalid date` when using milliseconds for the x-axis.

Comment: As x you need to have parsed timestamp and you cannot use function line Date.UTC() inside. To preparing JSON you should convert time.

Comment: Could you show jsfiddle demo with that issue and invalid dates?

Comment: @PawełFus : Edit 2 has more details

Comment: Try to use:  Email_Time.data.push(parseFloat(this.PROBE_START_TIME_MS), parseFloat(this.EMAIL));

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Still the same issue. Although, the code in Edit 3 is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

```
$.getJSON("Json_Data.cfm", {}, function(EmailResult) {
        var Email_Time = {
                        name: "Email",
                        type: "line",
                        color: "#A5BC4E",
                        data: [],
                        marker: {
                                   radius: 1
                                }
                };

        $.each(EmailResult.DATA, function() { 
                //alert(this);
                Email_Time.data.push(this);     // The line which had the issue.    
         });

            options.series[0] = Email_Time;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```